# Поменять страницы местами с помощью mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, apache, apache2, mod-rewrite

имеются две страницы на подобии https://site.com/page/test и https://site.com/superpage
Хочу чтобы по ссылке /page/test отображалось содержимое /superpage, а по ссылке /superpage отображалось содержимое /page/test, т.е. поменять их местами. Именно не редирект, а показать содержимое другой страницы, и при этом не зациклить выдачу. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это сделать средствами mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Задачу можно решить так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Предотвратить ошибку, связанную с бесконечным внутренним редиректом
# (Internal redirection: mapping an URL to another in the same virtual host)
# ->>>
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
# <<<-

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/test$
RewriteRule .* /superpage [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/superpage$
RewriteRule .* /page/test [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал, что такое есть